# How integrate svelte/sapper on existent express server?

Tags: svelte, sapper

I have an express server with handerbars to render views, and I want add sapper+svelte for new features. Also I will migrate the old code progressively.

Are there anyway to add sapper/svelte without broke the complete project?

Comment: I don't think you can just progressively add new features via sapper since it rolls its own server code. There are ways to add routes to sapper if you want that but I think it is much more difficult to do the other way round. Or you mount sapper as an external route. that might be an option but not mixing.

Comment: Yes, I think that is not easy and your solution is probably the less painful

Answer (score 0):

You can write a middleware to redirect all the requests to the sapper server via the existent express server

**or**

in sapper's default template change the current server form polka to express in server.js and then add all the existing routes to the express server

```js
import sirv from 'sirv';
import express from 'express';
import compression from 'compression';
import * as sapper from '@sapper/server';

const { PORT, NODE_ENV } = process.env;
const dev = NODE_ENV === 'development';

express() 
    .use(
        compression({ threshold: 0 }),
        sirv('static', { dev }),
        sapper.middleware()
    )
    .listen(PORT, err => {
        if (err) console.log('error', err);
    });
```

add all the routes the plugins the middleware and what not !!!